# PHP Login class

Tags: php, security

I wrote this PHP Login system and I would like to see if I have any errors/made any mistakes or if you think I can do something to improve it, like including tokenizing and improving security even more.

This script allows "Remember Me" option which uses a cookie and a session table to authorize a user. It has basic functions such as add/delete/modify user etc. There is an index page where a person can log in or register a new account. `Login` class which handles all the user interaction and securepage which user accesses when there is a successful log in.

index.php

```
<?php 
// Database definition for MySQL server
define("DB_HOST", "whatever.com");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");
?>


<?php 

// index.php

// Log In Script
// Main Page that allow users to log in and create new accounts

require_once('login.class.php');


$login = new Login();
$login->startSession();
$login->connectToDB();
$session_id = session_id();


// If the user has a cookie set, redirect him to secure page
if($login->isAuthorized()) {
    header("Location: securePage.php"); 
}

if($_POST['login']){

    // get the data, trim the blank spacesß
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    //if checked, the value will be 'on'
    //otherwise, it will be blank
    $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];

    // verify if the username and password are correct
    // and if rememberme is set to 'on', create a cookie

    if($username && $password){

        // Check the login details and redirect to securePage.php
        // if the password is not correct, notify the user
        $login->checkLogin($username, $password, $rememberme, $session_id);

    } else {

        echo("Please enter a username and password");

    }
}
if($_POST['create']){

    // create an account
    // and notify the user the account has been created
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $login->addUser($username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $email);


}

?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#table {
    width: 340px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="table">
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
Existing Users<hr/>
Username:
<input type="text" name="username"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"> Keep Me Logged In</input>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In"></input>
</form>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
New Users - Sign Up Below<hr/>
Username:
<input type="text" name="username"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
First Name:
<input type="text" name="first_name"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
Last Name:
<input type="text" name="last_name"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
E-Mail: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
<input type="text" name="email"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="create" value="Create A New Account"></input>
</form>


</div>
</html>
```

login.class.php

```
<?php 



// login.class.php
// This class contains most of the user's functionality 
/*
 *  MySQL Database Information Below
 *  the reason for password being 82 chars is because of the way the salt will be generated and added


// user table  
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `username` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR( 82 ) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR ( 64 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
    UNIQUE KEY ( `username`), 
    UNIQUE KEY ( `email` )
)

// table for storing cookie sessions
 * 
 You save the session_id in a cookie 
 and once the person visits the website again, 
 the page pulls up a cookie and gets session_id. 
 You then compare current ip and user agent to the ones stored in Session table. 
 After that, you pull up user's data based on user_id from users table.

CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`session_id` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
`user_ip` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
`user_agent` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`user_id` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) 

*/

// db defines
require_once('db_config.php');



// Salt Length for generateHash function
define('SALT_LENGTH', 9);

class Login {

    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $first_name; 
    private $last_name;
    private $email;
    private $session_id;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    // starts a session
    public function startSession(){
        session_start();
    }

    // Creates a new account based on a new user name and password
    // username must be unique
    // password gets md5 (hashed)
    // It also checks if username already exists
    public function addUser($username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $email){
        $username = $this->clean($username);
        $password = $this->generateHash($this->clean($password));
        $first_name = $this->clean($first_name);
        $last_name = $this->clean($last_name);
        $email = $this->clean($email);

        // Check if username already exists
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 0,5");    

        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die("Cannot perform query!");

        // Check if user name already exists and if it does not exist, create a new account

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
            echo "User's name already exists. Please pick another one!";        
        } else {

            // otherwise create an account
            $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $first_name . "'
                        , '" . $last_name . "', '" . $email . "')";       
            $result = mysql_query($query) OR die('Cannot perform query! Make sure you have filled out all the fields!');    
            echo "Your account has been created. You can now log in.";
        }
    }

    public function deleteUser($username){
        $username = $this->clean($username);
         // Check if username already exists
        $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";      

        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die("Cannot perform query!");
        $this->destroyCookieAndSession();
        header("Location: index.php");

    }

    // updates user's information
    public function updateUser($username, $password){

        $username = $this->clean($username);
        $password =  $this->generateHash($this->clean($password));

        $query = "UPDATE users SET password ='$password' WHERE username = '$username'";     

        //die();    
        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die("Cannot perform query!");
        echo "Your changes have been saved.<br/>";

    }

    // Check if the user account and password match the one in the database
    public function checkLogin($username, $password, $rememberme, $session_id) {

        $this->username = $this->clean($username);
        $this->password = $this->clean($password);
        $this->$session_id = $session_id;

        //extract the salt/hash from db and check if the hash/password is correct
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $this->username . "' LIMIT 0,1"; 

        $result = @mysql_query($query) OR die('Cannot perform query!'); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $dbHash = $row['password'];


        // generates hash based on the submitted password and stored salt
        $this->password = $this->generateHash($this->password, $dbHash);


        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $this->username . "' AND 
                password ='" . $this->password . "' LIMIT 0,1";                                             

        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die('Cannot perform query!');  


        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {     

            //set a cookie if rememberme is set to 'on' 

            if($rememberme == "on"){
                $this->setRememberMe($session_id);

        }

        // user has logged in successfuly, store all his information in this object 
        // before redirecting to securePage.php
        $this->setFirstName($row['first_name']);
        $this->setLastName($row['last_name']);
        $this->setEmail($row['email']);


        $this->createSession();
        header("Location: securePage.php");
        exit();

        } else {

            echo "Incorrect username or/and password.";
        }

        // frees the memory used by query   
        mysql_free_result($result);         
    }

    private function createSession(){


        // save state of this object before passing
        // php automatically serializes the object
        // and will automatically unserialize it

        $_SESSION['usrData'] = $this;

    }

    // sets the cookie
    // which allows the user to be logged into automatically
    private function setRememberMe($session_id){

        // check if the user id exists in the session db, if it does, delete that row

        $query = "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE user_id = '" . $this->getUsername() . "' LIMIT 0,5"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die("Cannot perform query!");

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
            $query = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE user_id = '" . $this->getUsername() . "'"; 
            $result = mysql_query($query) OR die("Cannot perform query!");
        }

        // insert the user's information into a session table
        $query = "INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, user_ip, user_agent, user_id) 
                  VALUES('" . $session_id . "', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', '" . 
                  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "', '" . $this->getUsername() . "')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die('Cannot perform query!!'); 

        // create a cookie with session_id         
        setcookie("autologin", $session_id, time() + 60*60*24*365, "/");

    }

    // check if the user has access to the page
    public function isAuthorized() {

        // check the session access
        if(isset($_COOKIE['autologin']) ) {

            // check if user information matches up
            // we do that by checking user agent and user ip information
            $session_id = $_COOKIE['autologin'];
            $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $user_agent =  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '" . $session_id . "'";                                         

            $result = mysql_query($query) OR die('Cannot perform query!');  

            // query the results only once since there's supposed to be only
            // one record for each session_id
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

            if ( $row["user_ip"] == $user_ip && $row["user_agent"] == $user_agent)
            {
                // if everything matches, create a new Login object based on user ID

                // Check if username already exists
                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $row["user_id"] . "' LIMIT 0,5";   
                $result2 = mysql_query($query2) OR die("Cannot perform query!");
                while ( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) ){
                    $this->username = $row2['username'];
                    $this->first_name = $row2['first_name'];
                    $this->last_name = $row2['last_name'];
                    $this->password = $row2['password'];
                    $this->email = $row2['email'];
                    $this->session_id = $session_id;
                } 

                $_SESSION['usrData'] = $this;
                return true;

            } else {
                // Information does not match
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            // if cookie is not set.
            return false;
        }

    }

    // private function that allows connection to the database 
    public function connectToDB() { 
        @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) OR die("Cannot connect to MySQL server!");    
        mysql_select_db("dig_login") OR die("Cannot select database!");
    }


    // Returns the username of a user
    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    // Returns the plain text password of a user
    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
    // Returns first name
    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->first_name;
    }
    // Returns last name
    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->last_name;
    }
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }
    //gets session
    public function getSessionID(){
        return $this->session;
    }


    // sets first name
    public function setFirstName($firstName) {
        $this->first_name = $firstName;
    }
    // sets last name
    public function setLastName($lastName) {
        $this->last_name = $lastName;
    }
    // sets email
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }


    // Escape bad input, sql injections, etc 
    private function clean($input) {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($input);
    }   

    // Kill the cookie
    public function destroyCookieAndSession(){
        setcookie('autologin', '', time()-42000, '/');
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

    }
    // This is a function that does the hashing
    // we are going to use sha256 as hashing algorithm 
    // If $salt is not passed, it creates a new salt
    // otherwise it extracts the salt from db 
    public function generateHash($password, $salt = null){

        if ($salt === null)
        {
            $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
        }
        else
        {
            $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);

        }


        return $salt . hash('sha256', $salt . $password);

    }

}
?>
```

securePage.php

```
<?php 
// securePage.php
// if the user has successfully logged in, this page will be shown.

// The form is generated by SESSION variables

require_once('login.class.php');
session_start();

// if session usr data does not exist, redirect to login page
if(!$_SESSION['usrData']){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$login = $_SESSION['usrData'];

// re-establish DB connection since Object's DB connection is not persistent
// once the object is passed through the session
$login->connectToDB();

echo "<br/>";
echo "Hello " . $login->getFirstName() . " " . $login->getLastName();
echo "<br/><br/>";



if( $_POST['save'] ){

    $login->updateUser(trim($_POST['username']), trim($_POST['password']));


}
if($_POST['delete']){

        $login->deleteUser(trim($_POST['username']));

}

// Logs out the user
if(isset($_GET['logout']) == "true"){
    $login->destroyCookieAndSession();
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<br/><br/>
<form action="securePage.php" method="post">
<hr/>
Username: <?php echo $login->getUserName(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $login->getUserName(); ?>"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Changes"></input>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Account"></input>
</form>
<hr/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="./securePage.php?logout=true">Log Out</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some note which was not mentioned before in other answers or comments.

If you redirect the users you shouldn't send them the form, so change

```
// Logs out the user
if(isset($_GET['logout']) == "true"){
    $login->destroyCookieAndSession();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

to

```
// Logs out the user
if(isset($_GET['logout']) == "true"){
    $login->destroyCookieAndSession();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit(); // or something like this - maybe return/die?
}
```

The same is true the other `header("Location: ...")` calls.

---

```
$result = mysql_query($query) 
    OR die('Cannot perform query! Make sure you have filled out all the fields!');
```

Maybe you want to change the simple `die()` calls to a more friendly error page. For example show the filled form and the error message so the user can correct the their input values without using the back button and without refilling every input box.

---

If your `username` attribute has an unique index you never get more than one results:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $row["user_id"] . "' LIMIT 0,5";   
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) OR die("Cannot perform query!");
while ( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) ){ ... }
```

If it happens somehow log the error and call a `die()` since it's an internal error.

Comment: Thanks man! When it comes to that mysql_query OR DIE statement, how would I just show the form with all the filled fields instead of DIE? Another thing is, if the account with the same name exists, that DIE statement still shows "Make sure you have filled out all the fields", how would I separate all those different cases instead of DIE statement?

Comment: Instead of the `die()` I would throw an exception and catch it somewhere then print its message as an error message. It needs some OOP knowledge but it makes error handling very easy. To be honest I haven't written any PHP code in the last 5-6 years but I'm sure that there are good frameworks which helps a lot with everyday form handling. I'd start the searching with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP

Comment: Yea try and catch is the way to go. I do have OOP knowledge. Just wanted to see if there was another way as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Initial thoughts:

Lots of redundant comments, for example:

```
// get the data, trim the blank spaces
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
```

Some obvious refactoring not implemented, for example:

```
if($_POST['create']){
    // create an account
    // and notify the user the account has been created
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
```

1. If you're always going to trim the data, just trim it, and never worry about it again.
2. If a chunk of code warrants a comment, it likely warrants a well-named method instead.

Is your HTML really not indented? Ew :(

`function addUser`

Missed refactoring, or at least remove redundant comments.

`function deleteUser`

You're not *checking* if username already exists, you're just trying to delete it. All of this function's comments can go in a function-level comment.

`function checkLogin`

Extraneous comments. Have to go through ~20 lines of code to see what happens if no `$result`; probably cleaner to flip conditional and handle the shorter case first.

`function setRememberMe`

Extraneous comments; all obvious from code.

`function isAuthorized()`

Too long, too much scanning to determine functionality. Consider something like this:

```
// Checks user login via information in autologin cookie.
public function isAuthorized() {
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['autologin'])) {
    return false;
  } 

    $session_id = $_COOKIE['autologin'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '" . $session_id . "'";                                         
    $result = mysql_query($query) OR die('Cannot perform query!');  
  $user_by_session = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $user_agent =  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (($user_by_session["user_ip"] != $user_ip) || ($user_by_session["user_agent"] != $user_agent)) {
      return false;
  }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $user_by_session["user_id"] . "' LIMIT 0,5";    
    $user_entries = mysql_query($query) OR die("Cannot perform query!");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_entries)) {
        $this->username   = $row['username'];
        $this->first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $this->last_name  = $row['last_name'];
        $this->password   = $row['password'];
        $this->email      = $row['email'];
        $this->session_id = $session_id;
    } 

    $_SESSION['usrData'] = $this;
    return true;
}
```

"Getter" functions: redundant comments.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make more comments more useful and remove redundant ones. Besides comments, how does everything else look. Are there any major security holes/mistakes that exist in the code?

Comment: @CodeCrack All of your SQL is subject to SQL injection because you don't SQL escape anything. Remember [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), and fear his parents.

Comment: I am running mysql_real_escape_string which is in my clean() function on all the user submitted input. Is that not good enough?

Comment: @CodeCrack Oh, missed that. Is the cookie encrypted? If not, could still be injected through that.

Comment: Hey Dave. How can the cookie be used to inject sql queries and what are the best ways to encrypt cookies?

Comment: @CodeCrack Because I can modify cookie values, and you use it directly. Just encode it like you do the parameters. Cookie values, if they're not already encrypted by PHP (I have no idea), can be encrypted using any mechanism, including [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).